# Need help on making spiral sphere and cone helix

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I was just wondering if anyone knew the proper input for plots like this?

[image: sphere]
[image: cone]

They don't have to be exactly the same. I just need to know the general format at the very least.

Comment: `ParametricPlot3D`?

Comment: For reference: [conical spiral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicalSpiral.html) and [spherical spiral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalSpiral.html).

Answer (score 6):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[50 t] Cos[t], Sin[50 t] Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
AspectRatio -> Automatic, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank-you very much. Any thoughts on the second graph?

Answer (score 5):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[50 t] Sin[t], Sin[50 t] Sin[t], t}, 
  {t, -π/2, π/2}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities for spirals; among them loxodromes geodesic helices and constant width involute types. From the given plots it is not always possible to guess well what type it belongs to. Pictured here is a Loxo cone. Due exponential variation with respect to polar angle a Loxo curve on first cone cannot cross over to the second cone nappe.

```
{rmin, ph, al, tmax} = {0.02, 0.35, 1.52, 70};  r[t_] = rmin Exp[Sin
[ph] Cot[al] t ]; ParametricPlot3D[r[t] {  Cos[t], Cot[ph] , Sin[t]},o 
{t, 0, tmax},   PlotLabel -> " LOXO_Cone ", PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red},
Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Loxo cone]

EDIT 1:

For other given lines on a cone with asymptotic circumferential behaviour shown one possibility is with integrals of

$$  b^2 \theta = \frac{\sqrt{r^4-a^4} d r }  {  r } $$

where ( $a,b$) are constants.  Solution $(\theta, r ) $ is in terms of tanh functions.

Answer (score -1):

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 == z^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 Mesh -> {10}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0]], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 Mesh -> {10}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0]], Boxed -> False, 
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Comment: These are *slices* of the sphere and cone as opposed to spirals, no?